# Refactoring a nested foreach

Tags: java

private List getEnumFromType(List vars, List enums) {
    List enumList = new ArrayList<>();

```
for (Bean.Var var : vars) {
    String typeWithoutTypeIdentifierPrefix = var.getType().substring(1,var.getType().length());
    for (Enum enumVal : enums) {
        if (typeWithoutTypeIdentifierPrefix.equals(enumVal.getName())) {
            if (!enumList.contains(enumVal)) {
                enumList.add(enumVal);
            }
        }
    }
}

return enumList;
```

}

Comment: Please improve your question quality. You can find more tips in: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages.

Comment: `forEach` is a `void` method. You cannot call anything on what `forEach` returns, because it doesn't return anything. Did you mean to use `map` instead of `forEach`?

Answer (score 0):

You have chained two terminal stream operators.

`.forEach()` returns void, hence the second `.forEach()` complains that it can't find a stream to work with.

You may want to read some of the [Java 8 Stream documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this.**

Don't get the idea that the Java 8 Stream API should be used every time you are looping through a collection. It's not a wildcard that you can use to replace all enhanced for loops, especially nested ones.

Your error occurs because you are trying to call `forEach` on the return value of `forEach`. Since your for loops are nested, the calls to `forEach` should also be nested in the stream version. The second for loop should be put in a place like this:

```
.forEach(countries -> countries.getFromZone().getCountries().stream().filter(country ->country.getCode().equals(selectedCountry).forEach(...))
```

But seriously, **Don't do this.**

Your code is very messy in the stream version. It is far less readable than the for loops, mainly because you have a nested for loop. Instead of trying to rewrite your code using streams, you should try to abstract out the logic of your current code. Extract some methods for example:

```
for (Rate rate : product.getrates()) {
    if (rateMatches(value)) { // I tried to guess what you are trying to do here. If you have better names please use yours
        for (Countrys countrys : rate.getFromCountry().getCountries()) {
            if (countrys.getCode().equals(selectedCountry)) {
                updateDisplay(value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way it's much more clearer.

Comment: or he could write with streams properly, so that code is actually more readable (see my answer). I agree that streams are not to be used in every scenario, but this one seems like a good one to me. First seek the data you want to use, and second update based on found data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate too much, think of it on simple terms. Keep in mind streams are also about making easier to follow code:

1. find all Rate/Countrys pairs that match your criteria
2. For each of them, update value accordingly.

Java streams approach (there are more alternatives):

```
public void yourMethod() {
    X product = ...;
    Y value = ...;
    Z selectedCountry = ...;

    if (product.getRates() == null || product.getRates().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    product.getRates().stream()
        .filter(r -> matchesValueRate(r, value))
        .flatMap(this::rateCountrysPairStream)
        .filter(p -> matchesSelectedCountry(p, selectedCountry))
        .forEach(p -> updateValue(p, v));
}

public boolean matchesValueRate(Rate candidate, Y value) {
    return value.getAtrribute().getRateType().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(candidate.getRateType().getCode()) && ...; // add your tzone filter also
}

public Stream<Pair<Rate, Countrys>> rateCountrysPairStream(Rate rate) {
    return rate.getFromCountry().getCountries().stream().map(c -> Pair.of(rate, c));
}

public boolean matchesSelectedCountry(Pair<Rate, Countrys> candidate, Z selectedCountry) {
    return selectedCountry.equals(candidate.second().getCode());
}

public void updateValue(Pair<Rate, Countrys> rateCountry, Y value) {
    Rate rate = rateCountry.first();
    Countrys country = rateCountry.second();
    // do your display stuff here
 }

 public static class Pair<K, V> {
     private final K first;
     private final V second;

     private Pair(K first, V second) {
         this.first = first;
         this.second = second;
     }

     public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> of(K first, V second) {
         return new Pair<>(first, second);
     }

     public K first() {
         return first;
     }

     public V second() {
         return second;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do i need to use pair<> ?can i use Map<>??

Comment: technically speaking, you could; but it would be weird IMO. Map design is to store multiple key-value mappings. Using it to store single entries will imply wasting resources in all jdk provided implementations. I have seen code reusing AbstractMap.SimpleEntry, but IMO this is again reusing stuff for what it was not designed for. Up to you in any case.